# Export projects as .jar in IntelliJ

Tags: build, jar, intellij-idea, export, artifact

I've recently switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ, and i'm a bit confused as to how to export projects as .jars. I've seen other posts, where the answer is to go to File > Project Structure > Artifacts, and add a new build artifact, and then use Build > Build Artifacts. However, I don't know where the jar is being saved, (if it is) and I would also like to know how to make it export to a custom location. I also think it's kind of strange how it takes IntelliJ around 20 or so seconds to compile the jar, while in Eclipse it only takes half a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use "Build on make" option. IntelliJ will make new jar for you on each "make" invocation. Assuming there were changes. Otherwise it will keep the existing jar.

Also, "Artifacts" configuration screen contains the location of the artifact.

[image]